# Vue components not loading

Tags: vue.js, laravel-5, vuejs2, vue-component

I was given this problematic codebase, where the Vue components aren't loading in.

Vue is mounting, but without any components.

This is a Laravel 5.7 app, using blade templates with some Vue added in.

**This is the initial code:**

```
import 'babel-polyfill'
import loadClientScripts from './load-client-scripts'
import 'bootstrap-material-design/js/'
// Vue & axios
import Vue from 'vue'
import { axios } from '../axios-config'

import BootstrapVue from 'bootstrap-vue/dist/bootstrap-vue.esm'

import { createLocales } from '../vue-i18n-config'
import Noty from 'noty'
//Components
import signInForm from './components/SignInForm'
import signUpForm from './components/SignUpForm'
import forgotPassForm from './components/ForgotPassForm'
// import RegisterToAgency from './components/RegisterToAgency'
import SendEmailForm from './components/SendEmailForm'
import AgencyServiceCategories from './components/AgencyServiceCategories'
import DropdownWithCheckboxes from './components/DropdownWithCheckboxes'
import LasiCoalitionAgencies from './components/LasiCoalitionAgencies'
import ServiceProviders from "./components/ServiceProviders";
import ServiceProvider from "./components/ServiceProvider";
import vSelect from "vue-select";

window.axios = axios

Vue.component('v-select', vSelect)

// Bootstrap Vue    
Vue.use(BootstrapVue)
export function createApp() {
  const i18n = createLocales(window.locale)

  // Components
  Vue.component('sign-in-form', signInForm)
  Vue.component('sign-up-form', signUpForm)
  Vue.component('forgot-pass-form', forgotPassForm)
  // Vue.component('register-to-agency', RegisterToAgency)
  Vue.component('send-email-form', SendEmailForm)
  Vue.component('agency-service-categories', AgencyServiceCategories)
  Vue.component('dropdown-with-checkboxes', DropdownWithCheckboxes)
  Vue.component('lasi-coalition-agencies', LasiCoalitionAgencies)
  Vue.component('service-providers', ServiceProviders)
  Vue.component('service-provider', ServiceProvider)


  new Vue({
    i18n
  }).$mount('#app')

}
```

**sign in form component for example:**

```
<template>
  <div>
    <b-form
      id="sign-in-form"
      @submit="onSubmit"
    >
      <div class="form-group">
        <b-form-input
          id="sgi-email"
          v-model="model.email"
          required
          name="email"
          :state="state('email')"
          type="email"
          :placeholder="$t('validation.attributes.email_address')"
        />
        <b-form-feedback>{{ feedback('email') }}</b-form-feedback>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group mb-3">
        <b-form-input
          id="sgi-password"
          v-model="model.password"
          required="required"
          name="password"
          :state="state('password')"
          type="password"
          :placeholder="$t('validation.attributes.password')"
        />
        <b-form-feedback>{{ feedback('password') }}</b-form-feedback>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group my-0">
        <a
          class="text-opacity forgot-pass-link"
          href="#"
        >
          {{ $t('labels.user.password_forgot') }}
        </a>
      </div>
    </b-form>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  console.log('IM HIT')
export default {
  name: 'SignInForm',
  data() {
    return {
      model: {
        email: '',
        password: ''
      },
      validation: {}
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    this.test()
  },
  methods: {
    test() {
      console.log("test")
    },
    feedback(name) {
      if (this.state(name)) {
        return this.validation.errors[name][0]
      }
    },
    state(name) {
      return this.validation.errors !== undefined &&
        this.validation.errors.hasOwnProperty(name)
        ? 'invalid'
        : null
    },
    onSubmit(evt) {
      evt.preventDefault()
      window.axios
        .post('/login', this.model)
        .then(response => {
          location.href = '/app'
        })
        .catch(e => {
          if (e.response.status === 422) {
            this.validation = e.response.data
            return
          }
        })
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Any ideas help!

in the example sign in form, the console does output the "Im hit" that I had placed to ensure that things were loaded.

Thanks

Comment: Well, why aren't they loading in? Is it giving you an error message of some sort? Did you check Vue.js dev-tools to see what the Vue runtime and its state are looking like in the background?

Comment: in the vue devtools, I see <Root> and nothing else. If I look in the console with $vm0, it has no children.

Comment: based on the code provided, there is nothing else. You're only registering the components. Is there any Vue mark-up actually using the components? Does the console report any error messages? If this is a fully designed app where the elements are suddenly disappearing, that means something went wrong in the rendering process pretty far up in the application (however, it does not look like that error is happening in the code posted, unless there is no HTML element with the ID `#app` in the HTML where this JS is embedded)

Comment: There is a #app, one of the first things I checked :P. Going to add in a component to the initial question.

Comment: I mean, based on the code you have, there is no component being passed to the `new Vue` instance, so even if you post mark-up, it could not be the markup being rendered by mounting that fresh Vue instance. You need to actually specify a component in the `new Vue` options, something like: `new Vue({i18n, render: h=>h(RootVueComponentHere)}).$mount('#app')` where `RootVueComponentHere` needs to be the root component (probably just a component with a `router-view` in it)

Comment: even if this is just some vue add-ons and not a SPA?

Answer (score 0):

Are you at any point rendering anything with that Vue instance?

Try passing a component to its render function like so:

```js
// lets pretend you've imported a component from some file App.vue up here and called the component simply 'App'
// e.g.: const App = require('./App.vue') or import App from './App.vue';
Vue.use(BootstrapVue)
export function createApp() {
  const i18n = createLocales(window.locale)

  // Components
  Vue.component('sign-in-form', signInForm)
  Vue.component('sign-up-form', signUpForm)
  Vue.component('forgot-pass-form', forgotPassForm)
  // Vue.component('register-to-agency', RegisterToAgency)
  Vue.component('send-email-form', SendEmailForm)
  Vue.component('agency-service-categories', AgencyServiceCategories)
  Vue.component('dropdown-with-checkboxes', DropdownWithCheckboxes)
  Vue.component('lasi-coalition-agencies', LasiCoalitionAgencies)
  Vue.component('service-providers', ServiceProviders)
  Vue.component('service-provider', ServiceProvider)


  new Vue({
    i18n,
    render: createElement => createElement(App) // needs a render function
  }).$mount('#app')

}
```

Comment: I've added in the imports that are on the file. Not sure how to format the render function with what I've got. this is the app.js file...

Comment: @JonYork Well, when the website/app first starts, what's the first page? Is there a component for that page? If not, you have to create one. You've registered the addon components, but to actually see them you have to use them within a component and then have the `new Vue` instance render it by setting the `render` property as shown above. As of right now, basically what you have is a blank application with a bunch of components that -could- be used but aren't being used anywhere.

Comment: @gabriel.hayes - What you've written seems to be based on the assumption that this is an SPA. Since they're using Blade templates, I suspect this is not the case. So there's no need to have an initial component as the Vue components are being embedded into an otherwise PHP-generated page. :)